# XBee printout, void setup()

Tags: printing, arduino, xbee

I'm having trouble with my XBee's printing out to the monitor a simple statement, within the void setup(), as shown in my program below.

It prints the GPS and various sensor data, but it skips the whole introductory sentences.  Whenever I open the arduino serial monitor, with the board plugged into my computer, it works fine.

Any suggestions?  I'm at a lost!

Thanks :)

```
// Temperature Sensor data, Air Quality, and GPS data update XBEE
//CSV format for user interpretation
//Last updated 11/5/14
//Amy Laguna

#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial XBee(2, 3);
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 7);

//Read temperature sensor on A1
int tempPin = 1;
//Read CO sensor on A0
int coPin = 0;
//Read Oxygen sensor on A2
int opin = 2;

//GPS setup
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);

//Use to debug
//SET to 'fale' to turn off echoing the GPS data to Serial
//Set to 'true' to debug and listen to raw GPS data
#define GPSECHO  false

// this keeps track of whether we're using the interrupt
boolean usingInterrupt = false;
void useInterrupt(boolean); 

void setup()  
{
    // connect at 115200 so we can read the GPS fast enough and echo without dropping chars
    XBee.begin(115200);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(5000);
    XBee.println("Vehicle GPS, Temperature, and Air Quality Data!");
    delay(2000);
    XBee.println("Note: Elevation in Pensacola Florida:   ~ 31 m (102 ft)");
    XBee.println();
    XBee.println("\n Date:            Time:         Fix:              Location:          Speed (mph):       Elevation:       CO:          O2:                Temperature: ");

    // 9600 NMEA is the default baud rate for Adafruit MTK GPS's
    GPS.begin(9600);

    // RMC (recommended minimum) and GGA (fix data) including altitude
    GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);

    // Set the update rate
    GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);   // 1 Hz update rate
    // For the parsing code to work nicely and have time to sort thru the data, and
    // print it out we don't suggest using anything higher than 1 Hz

    useInterrupt(true);

    delay(1500);
}

// Interrupt is called once a millisecond, looks for any new GPS data, and stores it
SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
    char c = GPS.read();
    // if you want to debug, this is a good time to do it!
#ifdef UDR0
    if (GPSECHO)
        if (c) UDR0 = c;  
#endif
}

void useInterrupt(boolean v) {
    if (v) {
        // Timer0 is already used for millis() - we'll just interrupt somewhere
        // in the middle and call the "Compare A" function above
        OCR0A = 0xAF;
        TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
        usingInterrupt = true;
    } else {
        // do not call the interrupt function COMPA anymore
        TIMSK0 &= ~_BV(OCIE0A);
        usingInterrupt = false;
    }
} 

uint32_t timer = millis();
void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
    if (! usingInterrupt) {
        // read data from the GPS in the 'main loop'
        char c = GPS.read();
        // if you want to debug, this is a good time to do it!
        if (GPSECHO)
            if (c) XBee.print(c);
    }

    // if a sentence is received, we can check the checksum, parse it...
    if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {

        if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
            return;  // we can fail to parse a sentence in which case we should just wait for    another
    }

    // if millis() or timer wraps around, we'll just reset it
    if (timer > millis())  timer = millis();

    // approximately every 2 seconds or so, print out the current stats
    if (millis() - timer > 2000) { 
        timer = millis();   // reset the timer
        PrintGPS();        //Print GPS readings
        PrintAirQuality();     //Print CO and Temperature readings
    }
}

void PrintGPS()
{
    //Print Date, Time, Fix
    XBee.print("\n");
    XBee.print(GPS.month, DEC); XBee.print('/');
    XBee.print(GPS.day, DEC); XBee.print("/20");
    XBee.print(GPS.year, DEC);
    XBee.print(" ,     ");
    XBee.print(GPS.hour, DEC); XBee.print(':');
    XBee.print(GPS.minute, DEC); XBee.print(':');
    XBee.print(GPS.seconds, DEC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a longer delay before the `XBee.println()` statements.  If the radio modules haven't associated yet, they won't be ready for you to start sending data through them.

Alternatively, wait until the first call to `PrintGPS()` and send it then:

```
void PrintGPS()
{
    static int first_time = 1;

    if (first_time) {
        print_headers();
        first_time = 0;
    }
    //Print Date, Time, Fix
    ...
```